# Passing a variable into a stored procedure call using Talend Open Source

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, talend, edi

I want to call an SP in Talend like the following:

```
`/ Declare a variable that references the type. /  
DECLARE @LocationTVP AS LocationTableType;




/ Add data to the table variable. /  
INSERT INTO @LocationTVP (LocationName, CostRate)  
    SELECT Name, 0.00  
    FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.StateProvince;  



/ Pass the table variable data to a stored procedure. /  
EXEC usp_InsertProductionLocation @LocationTVP;`
```

Can this be done in Talend Open Source? If so, how?

Comment: Did you try the t*YourDB*SP components ? They can be used to make some stored-procedure calls.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, This might be helpful for you.

[Calling a stored procedure or function](https://help.talend.com/reader/Q9vaxgWJukCTTBvQLU1sYA/1YRfa8jzKBb5GYYBOQsEHg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tMssqlInput() component to call for Stored procedure.
In the Query Builder, just type "EXEC your_sp_name '"+context.from_date+"','"+context.to_date+"', "+context.var+""
Before calling stored procedure from tMssqlInput(), you should store the dynamic variable value in the context parameters .
Typically your job flow would be like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K83eF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I used **tMSSQLInput** component but, it didn't work for me.

We can execute SQL Server stored procedure in Talend along with the context variables using **tMSSQLRow** component. Works like charm for me

But, few things to note:

1. I gave **tMSSQLConnection** and then connected it with **tMSSQLRow** (*with a stored procedure inside this component*). This didn't work.
2. So I had to remove the tMSSQLConnection and enter the connection details in the tMSSQLRow component itself. This worked for me.

Enter stored procedure in this format:

**"EXEC schema_name.procedure_name " '"+context.argument1+"','"+context.argument2+"'**